# WinDbg: How do I include a thread id and time value in a breakpoint .printf _without_ using pseudo registers?

Tags: windbg

I have some breakpoint "pairs," and I'd like to measure the time in between when they are hit.

The simplest thing that would allow me to do this is to include some sort of timestamp (even if it's just clock ticks or something) in the `.printf` I use when the breakpoint is hit.

I could use the [pseudo registers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/pseudo-register-syntax#automatic-pseudo-registers) `$tid` and `$dbgtime` in the breakpoint code. When I do, the performance *really* suffers.

```
bp1000 ucrtbase!malloc ".printf \"[0x%08x] [ucrtbase] [0x%04x] [0x%08x] malloc(%d): \", $dbgtime, $tid, dwo(@esp), dwo(@esp+4); gc "
```

When the same code is used (without using meaningful values for timestamp and thread id), things work *much* better.

```
bp1000 ucrtbase!malloc ".printf \"[0x%08x] [ucrtbase] [0x%04x] [0x%08x] malloc(%d): \", 0, 0, dwo(@esp), dwo(@esp+4); gc "
```

Is there some other (high-performance) way to get this information? The current time is more valuable than the thread ID. I can always make the breakpoint only apply to a specific thread so that emitting the ID is only sugar.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
0:000> bp ucrtbase!malloc "~# ; .echotime ; dd @$csp l2 ; gc ;"
0:000> bl
 0 e 00007ff8`ab61c9e0     0001 (0001)  0:**** ucrtbase!malloc "~# ; .echotime ; dd @$csp l2 ; gc ;"
0:000> g
.  0  Id: 1a84.1f14 Suspend: 1 Teb: 00000018`f49d1000 Unfrozen
      Start: cdb!wmainCRTStartup (00007ff6`efd2bbf0)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: f
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Wed Aug  7 22:17:44.992 2019 
00000018`f47eeb58  ab622762 00007ff8
.  0  Id: 1a84.1f14 Suspend: 1 Teb: 00000018`f49d1000 Unfrozen
      Start: cdb!wmainCRTStartup (00007ff6`efd2bbf0)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: f
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Wed Aug  7 22:17:44.992 2019 (UTC + 5:30)
00000018`f47eeb08  ab622762 00007ff8
```